# Matematical operations with zabbix items

Tags: network-monitoring, system-monitoring, zabbix

I need to apply some mathematical formulas on some items of a zabbix host,

For example I want to have a graph with the mean of traffic for all realtek interfaces I have in my network, can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to make use of either [calculated items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated) or [aggregate checks](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/aggregate).